# empty image from blob storage

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

This is how I try to upload an image to Azure blog storage, then upload an empty file located there.

[image: Azure image 1]

[image: Info about Blob storage]

I try to upload this image here:

```
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = new CloudStorageAccount(new Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Auth.StorageCredentials(Accountname, KeyValue), true);
            // Create the blob client.
            CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

            // Retrieve a reference to a container.
            CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(ContainerValue);

            CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(filename);
            using (var f = System.IO.File.Open(model.FileToUpload.FileName, FileMode.Create))
            {
                await blockBlob.UploadFromStreamAsync(f);
            }
```

But if i try to open this image say this.

[image: error with image.] From danish to english: **We can not open this file**

Comment: What do you expect to open if the file is empty?

Comment: i check this file not empty. @juunas

Comment: Ahh, sorry, misunderstood your question title :)

Comment: Please try to reset the stream’s position to zero before uploading. Add following line of code just before you call UploadFromStream method: f.Position(0). Hope this helps.

Comment: Is your method also `async Task` and not `async void`?

Comment: @juunas `async Task`

Comment: its say : **Non-invocable member 'FileStream.Position' cannot be used like a method.** @GauravMantri

Comment: Sorry, can you try f.Position = 0?

Comment: The same problems... @GauravMantri

Comment: The System.IO.File.Open call is using FileMode.Create. This is creating or overwriting the file. I think this should be FileMode.Open.

Comment: now its error after i make this u say: "FileNotFoundException"

Answer (score 1):

As Marco said, FileMode.Create specifies that the operating system should **create a new file**. If the file already exists, it will be **overwritten**.
For more details, you could refer to this [article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filemode(v=vs.110).aspx).

According to the pictures you provided, your blob size is **0 B**. So, you would always couldn't find the file and open it.
FileMode specifies how the operating system should open a file.

So I suggest that you could delete it and use **OpenRead** to open an existing file for reading. You could refer to the code as below:

```
using (var f = System.IO.File.OpenRead(model.FileToUpload.FileName))
            {
                await blockBlob.UploadFromStreamAsync(f);
            }
```

Comment: Error are: FileNotFoundException after i try to upload this file.

Comment: Did you use OpenRead to open the file? Where you get the not found exception?

Comment: yea i do.`using (var f = System.IO.File.OpenRead(fValue))
                {
                    await blockBlob.UploadFromStreamAsync(f);
                }`

Comment: You could try to set you blob name as a specific name. And set the specific path of your image as the fValue to check if you have upload the image. Also, you could debug your code to check if your file have its file length.